# Showing xml elements in an HTML table using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in XSLT.I have an XML file and I want to use xslt to show the information in the xml file into a table. but I can the information in a row like this:

`apfel 8.97 Fa. Krause Kirschen 10.45 Fa. Helbig apfel 12.67 Fa. Liebig` 
this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/First.xsl"?>
<lieferungen xmlns="urn:myspace:lieferungen"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:myspace:lieferungen ....">
  <artikel id="3526">
    <name>apfel</name>
    <preis stueckpreis="true">8.97</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
  </artikel>
  <artikel id="7866">
    <name>Kirschen</name>
    <preis stueckpreis="false">10.45</preis>
    <lieferant>Fa. Helbig</lieferant>
  </artikel>
</lieferungen>
```

and here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <h1>The First XSLT in diesem Jahr</h1>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Artikel</td>
          <td>Preis</td>
          <td>Liferant</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="artikel">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="preis"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="lieferant"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only small problems in your xslt.
The main one is, that your XML has an **default namespace**. Therefore you need to add this namespace with an prefix to your stylesheet. Something like:
`xmlns:my="urn:myspace:lieferungen"`

Than you have to use the new prefix `my` for any access to an element form default namespace.
E.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="my:artikel">
```

Second: Your for-each loop iterate over artikel therefor you need to be in liefrant element to make this work. Change your template to `<xsl:template match="/*">`

Therefor try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:my="urn:myspace:lieferungen" >
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <h1>The First XSLT in diesem Jahr</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Artikel</td>
                    <td>Preis</td>
                    <td>Liferant</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="my:artikel">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="my:name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="my:preis"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="my:lieferant"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<html xmlns:my="urn:myspace:lieferungen">
  <h1>The First XSLT in diesem Jahr</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Artikel</td>
      <td>Preis</td>
      <td>Liferant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>apfel</td>
      <td>8.97</td>
      <td>Fa. Krause</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kirschen</td>
      <td>10.45</td>
      <td>Fa. Helbig</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: thnk you for your answer, I found somehow my problem, Th eproblem was the path of the `Firs.xsl` file in the xml file. If I put the absoulute path. It works, but now I  have another problem. I can only show the HTML table and not the information in the xml file

Answer (score 2):

I offer another solution (also if I think that hr_117 offered a better one solution). Anyway I hope this may help you.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lieferungen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:myspace:lieferungen ....">
   <artikel id="3526">
       <name>apfel</name>
       <preis stueckpreis="true">8.97</preis>
       <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
   </artikel>
   <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">10.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Helbig</lieferant>
   </artikel>
</lieferungen>
```

In the XML I removed the default namespace.
And now the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <h1>The First XSLT in diesem Jahr</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Artikel</td>
      <td>Preis</td>
      <td>Liferant</td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="//lieferungen/artikel">
        <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="preis|lieferant"/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</html>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
   <td><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="preis">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lieferant">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></td>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This generatre the following html:

```
<html>
    <h1>The First XSLT in diesem Jahr</h1>
    <table border="1">
       <tr>
           <td>Name</td>
           <td>Artikel</td>
           <td>Preis</td>
           <td>Liferant</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>apfel</td>
           <td>3526</td>
           <td>8.97</td>
           <td>Fa. Krause</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>Kirschen</td> 
           <td>7866</td>
           <td>10.45</td>
           <td>Fa. Helbig</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</html>
```

Comment: thnks buddy, very nice :)